# Must a positively oriented path be simple, closed and piecewise smooth?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv5ln.png) Ch1, Ch4

> 1. **Question 1**: Do all paths have an orientation?

The following is a quote from Ch1 of the book: 'Figure 1.8 shows two examples. We remark that each path comes with an **orientation**, i.e. a sense of direction.'

Should I interpret as that the paths in Fig 1.8 have orientations, but not necessarily other paths? Or that the paths in Fig 1.8 are examples to say that any path has an orientation? Or what?

> 2. **Question 2**: In re (Q1) above and the definition below, are there definitions for a path to be positively oriented even though it is not simple, piecewise smooth or closed?

Definition of positively oriented: 'A piecewise smooth simple closed path $\gamma$ is **positively oriented** if it is parametrised s.t. its inside is on the left as the parametrisation traverses $\gamma$. An example is a counter-clockwise oriented circle.'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Paths have orientation.  Theorem 4.18 and  4.20 above hold regardless of the orientation, and 4.27 requires positive orientation.  It looks like you book is precise in that it uses "positively oriented" when it is necessary.

Comment: No, a "path" does not necessarily have a direction.  A "directed path" or "oriented path" is a path together with one of the two possible orientations specified.  Of course, integrating a function, f, along a given path, "from A to B" is different from the integration "from B to A"- in fact one is the negative of the other.  In order to talk about integration on a path, that path must be "directed" or "oriented".

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Edited to be hopefully clearer or less broad. Thanks!

Comment: @DougM Edited question. Do you disagree with user 247327? Thanks!

Comment: @user247327 Edited question. Do you disagree with DougM? Thanks!

Comment: (1). Yes, but you should understand that definitions is just language, not content. A different author could perfectly not attach orientations to their definition of the word "path". In complex analysis and integration orientation of the path is relevant to the theorems (the content). That is why it is convenient to have it as part of the definition of path.

Comment: @fatherBrown Well yeah, that's why I asked about the quote. Thanks!

Comment: For a path that is not closed, there may be no "inside" and "outside", so no way to define "positively oriented". For paths that are not simple, there may be several "insides", and no consistent way to define "positively oriented".

Comment: @RobertIsrael ah thanks! What about simple, closed but not piecewise smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a path that is not closed, there may be no "inside" and "outside", so no way to define "positively oriented". For paths that are not simple, there may be several "insides", and no consistent way to define "positively oriented". – Robert Israel Aug 11 at 0:49
>
> @RobertIsrael ah thanks! What about simple, closed but not piecewise smooth? – BCLC Aug 11 at 1:03