# How important is the assumption $\gamma$ is positively oriented? (Residues, Cauchy's Thm from Cauchy's Integral Formula)

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, residue-calculus

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 4.32, Cor 8.27

> Question 1. Should the following 2 statements in the textbook have an assumption that the path $\gamma$ in question is positively oriented?
>
> Question 2. Are there ways to forego assuming $\gamma$ is positively oriented? Eg 'If $\gamma$ is [simple, piecewise smooth and closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876078) but not positively oriented, then $-\gamma$ is' or something. This may be a Calculus III issue.

-

2 statements:

-

> 1. (Cor 8.27) Suppose $f$ is a function that is holomorphic in $A = \{R_1 < |z-z_0| < R_2\}$ with Laurent series $$f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k (z-z_0)^k$$ If $\gamma$ is any simple, closed, piecewise smooth, path in $A$ s.t. $z_0 \in int(\gamma)$, $$\int_{\gamma} f = 2\pi i c_{-1}$$

- Reason: [At the start of Ch9.2 on Residues, the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPV2D.png) restates Cor 8.27 but with an assumption that $\gamma$ is positively oriented.

> 2. (Exer 4.32) Show that the corollary (Cor 4.20) to Cauchy's Thm (Thm 4.18) is a corollary to Cauchy's Integral Formula (Formula 4.27) if $\gamma$ is simple.

- Reason: Cauchy's Integral Formula (Formula 4.27) assumes $\gamma$ is positively oriented while Cor 4.20 doesn't.

Comment: The statement of 8.27 makes no sense for several reasons. Did you state it _exactly_ as it appeared in the book? If yes: You need a better book. If no: You should be much more careful - the little changes you made that meant the same thing really don't mean the same thing at all.

Comment: In particular (i) saying $z_0\in A$ and then later saying $\forall z_0[\dots]$ makes no sense logically (ii) If $z_0\in A$ and $c_{-1}$ is the coefficient in the Laurent series for $f\in H(A)$ centered at $z_0$ then $c_{-1}=0$, because that Laurent series is a power series! I tend to suspect that $z_0$ is actually the center of $A$ - if so then you should say so; note that if $z_0$ is the center of $A$ then $z_0\notin A$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks! Screenshots are apparently bad, and it was too time consuming to do word for word, at least in the short run because I guess it's more time consuming in the long run having to edit or explain.

Comment: Right. I don't know if you noticed, but you didn't quite answer my question. _Does_ the book say exactly what you wrote or not? If not you really should change the question to say what the book says. Would make the question  much better. _Also_ quoting someone incorrectly is a bad bad thing! The authors would be very unhappy with you if they knew you claimed the book contained that sort of nonsense.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich not the same thanks for the reminder. I'll edit later

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah ok I see the problem. I believe it's supposed to be 's.t. z_0 \in \int(\gamma)$' not '$\forall z_0 \in int(\gamma)$'

Comment: A day later and you still can't be bothered to tell me whether it really says $z_0\in A$ or, as would make more sense, that $z_0$ is the center of $A$. _Wow_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich centre as I edited...?

Comment: Fine. Much better - sorry about reading that comment and not looking for changes to the answer. (Didn't have time, heh...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $-\gamma$ is the reverse of contour $\gamma$, $\oint_{-\gamma} f = - \oint_\gamma f$.  So the formula of Cor. 8.27 can't be true for both $\gamma$ and $-\gamma$: you do need to assume $\gamma$ is positively oriented.

On the other hand, Cor. 4.20 says $\oint_\gamma f = 0$: if that's true for $\gamma$, it's also true for $-\gamma$, so this does not need to assume positively oriented.

Comment: Thanks Robert Israel! May you please help here? [How important is the assumption $\gamma$ is positively oriented? (Cauchy's Thm from Green's Thm, Integrating power series)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875884) Also here [Can a path: 1. have no orientation? 2. be positively oriented but not simple, piecewise smooth or closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876078) ?